# PGFPLOTS doesn't work correctly when I "change" the graph scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [name=plot, ymin=0,ymax=3,xmin=0,xmax=1,
    xlabel = $L$,
    ylabel = {$T$},
    legend pos=north west,
  scatter/classes={%
    a={mark=o,draw=black}}]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[meta=label] {
x y label
0.650  1.6 a
0.606  1.56 a
0.581 1.54 a
0.555 1.51 a 
0.526 1.47 a 
0.502 1.4 a     
};\label{puntos}
    ]

\addplot [
    color=red,
]
{-6.2065*x^2+8.4139*x-1.251};\label{Func}


\end{axis}

 \node[anchor=north west, draw=black, fill=white] (legend) at (plot.north west) {\begin{tabular}{l l}
 Ajuste & \ref{Func}\\
 Datos & \ref{puntos}
\end{tabular}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you be a bit more specific? What exactly do you change, and how exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: I see your ylabel is missing from the screenshot, but if I put your code in a minimal document it is present (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wysUv.png), so if you could make a complete, minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, containing *only* the parts needed to demonstrate the problem, that might make it a lot easier to diagnose.

Comment: Hi!, the problem is that when I change the scale of the axes it stops being circular and becomes straight lines. I'd like know how solve it. Thanks

Comment: when i say scale i refer to ymin,xmin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the plot of the quadratic? The default setting of `pgfplots` for plots of functions is to calculate 25 samples in the range -5:5, meaning that when you set `xmin=0, xmax=1`, you get just three sample points in that range. Also by default `pgfplots` draws straight lines between each sample point, so you get the result seen in your plot.

The main two parameters to be aware of here is `domain` which sets the range over which function values are calculated, and `samples` which sets the number of (equally spaced) sample points within that range.

For your case, if you do

```
\addplot [
    color=red,
    domain=0:1
]
{-6.2065*x^2+8.4139*x-1.251};
```

that gets you 25 sample points from zero to one, and the plot looks like this:

[image]

If that isn't smooth enough, you could add e.g. `samples=50`.